how to download file from express res.download() using axios
client.js // using vue
function downloadFile() {
      api
        .get(`/download`, {
          responseType: "blob",
          params: { fileName: downloadFilename.value },
          // headers: {
          //     'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
          // }
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(Object.keys(response));
          console.log(response.data);
          console.log(typeof response.data);
          console.log(response.headers); // does not include content-disposition
          console.log("File downloading successfully!");
          try {
            new File([response.data], "/tmp/" + downloadFilename.value);
            console.log("after new File line");
          } catch (e) {
            console.log("file blob save error?");
            console.log(e);
          }
          console.log("hello from downloadFile");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("File could not be downloaded:", error);
        });
    }

server.js
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  let {fileName} = req.query
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    console.log('im here in download hhhh ')
    res.download(filePath, (error) => {console.log('res.download error: ' + error)});
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({status: 'file not found'})
  } 
});

I am a newb with Javascript. I can download it by using a browser "http://localhost/download?fileName=test.mp4", but can't seem to download it using axios.
I wonder if ArrayBuffer will be better than Blob?

I guess simulating element click is the way. Thank you
